# nice() method for ticks in nvd3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have been working on nvd3 , in d3.js to make the ticks look good their is a nice() provided for ex.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                .range([225,50]).nice();
```

but in case of nvd3 , this nice() is not working , i have tried many things 
such as :

```
//   chart.yAxis.scale().nice();                     not working
 //  chart.yAxis.scale(d3.scale.linear().nice());     not working
```

So how can i use this nice function in nvd3 or else their is any other alternative  ?

Answer (score 0):

`nice` method will only make range limits look good. To make every tick look same way - set `d3.interpolateRound` as interpolator of the linear scale